# Newbie's code not working

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning Javascript and writing my first pieces of code. This one is supposed to capture text input and add it to a list, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I've been looking at it for half an hour and I can't see where I went wrong. Would you mind giving me a hand?

window.onload = init;

```
function init() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
    textInput.onKeyPress = handleKeyPress;
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    loadPlaylist();
}

function handleKeyPress() {
    if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {
        handleButtonClick;
    }

    function handleButtonClick() {
        var songName = textInput.value;
        if (songName == "") {
            alert("Please enter a song");
        } else {
            var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
            var songName = textInput.value;
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = songName;
            var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
            ul.appendChild(li);
            save(songName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The one issue I can see is that you are calling a method handleButtonClick incorrectly:

```
if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {handleButtonClick;}
```

it should be:

```
if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {handleButtonClick();}
```

**Update**:
There were a few more errors, this should work:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
    textInput.onKeyPress = handleKeyPress;
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    //loadPlaylist();  Dont have this code
}

function handleKeyPress() {
if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {
    handleButtonClick;
        }
    }

function handleButtonClick() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput"); //This moved up for songname
    var songName = textInput.value;
    if (songName == "") {
        alert("Please enter a song");
    } else {
        var songName = textInput.value;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = songName;
        var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(li);
        //save(songName);  Dont have this code
    }
}
```

Comment: It should also be using `.key` or `.char` since `.keyCode` is for legacy engines.

Comment: Thanks Steve (also, Ahmet). Fixing that returns this error after I type some text and press the button / hit enter:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. You forgot to end your function with `}`

```
 window.onload = init;
    function init() {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
        textInput.onKeyPress = handleKeyPress;
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
        loadPlaylist();}
    function handleKeyPress(){
        if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {handleButtonClick;}
        }
    function handleButtonClick() {
        var songName = textInput.value;
        if (songName == "") {alert("Please enter a song");}
        else {
            var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
            var songName = textInput.value;
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = songName;
            var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
            ul.appendChild(li);
            save(songName);}}
```

After today, use your console before asking question.

Mozilla : `CTRL + SHIFT + K`

IE : `F12`

Chrome: `SHIFT + CTRL + I`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a textInput variable in function init(), which is completely inaccessible to the same named variable that is used in but not declared in function handleButtonClick().

Comment: I thought I was making textInput global, isn't that the case?

Comment: JavaScript allows accidental creation of global variables, which is a tremendous mistake.  Never rely upon this.  Always declare your variables in the intended scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move handleButtonClick to outer scope, and also invoke `handleButtonClick()` .

```
function handleButtonClick() {
    var songName = textInput.value;
    if (songName == "") {
        alert("Please enter a song");
    } else {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
        var songName = textInput.value;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = songName;
        var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(li);
        save(songName);
    }
}

function handleKeyPress() {
    if (textInput.keyCode == 13) {
        handleButtonClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. loadPlaylist function is not there.
2. In handleKeyPress(), textinput is not defined
3. handleButtonClick should be invoked as handleButtonClick();

I suggest you to check each function at a time and not the entire code together.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/QbH4u/

**Code clean up suggestions from fiddle**
*Error:
Problem at line 9 character 24: 'handleKeyPress' was used before it was defined.
function handleKeyPress() {
Problem at line 11 character 9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
handleButtonClick;
Problem at line 14 character 31: 'handleButtonClick' was used before it was defined.
function handleButtonClick() {
Problem at line 16 character 22: Use '===' to compare with ''.
if (songName == "") {
Problem at line 19 character 27: 'textInput' was used before it was defined.
var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
Problem at line 20 character 26: 'songName' is already defined.
var songName = textInput.value;
Implied global: handleButtonClick 5,11, loadPlaylist 6, textInput 10,15, alert 17, save 25
Unused variable: handleButtonClick 9 handleKeyPress*